# How to extract the datas from an array with different field in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

My array is:

```
Array ( [0] => 652, 5850 [1] => 230, 9850 [2] => 201 ,13700 )
```

I stored the data by using this code:

```
$myarray=array();
if(!empty($_GET['check_list'])) {
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_GET['check_list'] as $selected) {
        $myarray[]=$selected;
    }
    print_r($myarray);
}
```

I want to extract this data like:

```
[roomno] =>652,230,201
[price]  =>5850,9850,13700
```

How can I get this value?

Comment: are you sure the sample provided is correct? ...the content of of each index is an array or a string  ?.. in you sample are both wrong ..

Comment: i edited sir please check

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/gWsJ2btK

Comment: Thanks @AniketSahrawat sir.. its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible way :

```
<?php

$array = [
    0 => [652, 5850],
    1 => [230, 9850],
    2 => [201 ,13700]
];

$roomno = [];
$price = [];

foreach($array as $a){
    $roomno[] = $a[0];
    $price[] = $a[1];
}
```